# Multiply list by all elements of the list except at it's own index

Tags: python, list, numpy

I'm trying to build a function that given a list will return a list with the elements multiplied together, excluding the element that was at the same index. For example for the list `[1,2,3,4]` it would return `[2*3*4,1*3*4,1*2*3]`.
This is what I tried

```
import numpy as np
def my_function(ints):
products = np.ones(len(ints))
indices = range(0,len(ints))
for i in ints:
    if i != indices[i]
        products *=ints[i]
return products
```

I think my problem was that I was thinking that "i" would be referencing the indices rather than values of those indices.

1. How can I create something that will reference the indices rather than the values
2. Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: there is probably a clever one-liner to do what you want... but I will just comment on how to get the indices when iterating: use the `enumerate` builtin function, e.g. `for i, value in enumerate(mylist):`

Comment: `enumerate()` will give you both value and iterator. Otherwise, use a range loop.

Comment: Easiest and probably fastest is to find the product of all elements, and then divide it by each element to get the result. But it may overflow if using fixed-length ints.

Answer (score 6):

with `numpy` this is easy:

```
import numpy as np
def fun(input):
    arr = np.array(input)
    return arr.prod() / arr
```

Answer (score 3):

Taking from @interjay's comment:

```
from operator import mul

total = reduce(mul, ints)
multiplied = [total/y for y in ints]
```

Answer (score 3):

Solution with `enumerate`:

```
def my_function(ints):
    res = []
    for i, el in enumerate(ints):
        res.append(reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, ints[:i] + ints[i+1:]))
    return res

print my_function([1,2,3,4])
>>> [24, 12, 8, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

with list comprehension

```
array_of_nums = np.random.rand(10)
[np.prod([i for x, i in enumerate(array_of_nums) if x != e]) for e, y in enumerate(array_of_nums)]
```

Answer (score 1):

### without using division

```
    import numpy as np
    
    def remainingProduct(arr):
        a = arr
        list1 = []
        n = len(arr)
        for i in range(0, n):
            b = a[0]
            a.remove(a[0])
            c = np.prod(a)
            list1.append(c)
            a.append(b)
        return list1
    
    # print(remainingProduct([3, 2, 1]))#[2, 3, 6].
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here's an easy approach**

```
def mul_numbers(nums):
    new_arr = []
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        product = 1
        for j in range(len(nums)):
            if nums[i] != nums[j]:
                product *= nums[j]
        new_arr.append(product)

    return new_arr


arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
result = mul_numbers(arr)
print(result)

>>> [120, 60, 40, 30, 24]
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using reduce:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul

l = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4]
# Modified to work with lists that contain dupes thanks to the feedback in comments
print [reduce(mul, l[:i]+l[i+1:], 1) for i in xrange(len(l))]
>>> [48, 24, 24, 16, 12]
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to incorporate enumerate into your code is

```
import numpy as np
def intmult(ints):
    products = np.ones(len(ints))
    for i,j in enumerate(ints):
        products *= ints[i]
    for i,j in enumerate(products):
        products[i] /= ints[i]
    return products
```

Note that this doesn't cover the case where one of the elements is 0.

Answer (score 0):

**without using any library**

just dont forget to append new array for loop first with proper indentation.

```
def f(arr):
    new_arr = []
    for i in arr: #loop first
        p = 1
        for j in arr:
            if i!=j:
                p =  p*j
        new_arr.append(p) #append for loop first
    return new_arr
arr = [2, 3, 4,5]
f(arr)
```

**its bit confusing but works [not recommended]**

```
def f(arr):
    n = len(arr)
    left = [1]*n
    right = [1]*n
    product_array = []

    # build left array
    for i in range(1,n):
        left[i] = left[i-1] * arr[i-1]
    # build right array
    for i in range(1,n):
        right[i] = right[i-1] * arr[::-1] [i-1]
    
    # build product arr from subarrays
    for i in range(n):
        product_array.append(left[i] * right[::-1][i])
    return product_array

arr = [2, 3, 4,5]
f(arr)
```